# Snackbar getAnchorView() vs. parent view

Tags: android, material-design, android-snackbar, snackbar

I have read the Snackbar [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/snackbar/Snackbar#make)

but wasn't sure about the difference between snackbar's `parentTarget` (parent view) and `anchoredView`.

Please correct me if I'm wrong:

1) `parent view` is the view from which the snackbar walks up the hirerchy view to find a `suitable parent view`.

2) The suitable parent view isn't the anchoredView.

What happens when one sets a `parentView` (required by the ctor) and also `anchoredView`?

Where would the snackbar open?

Comment: Have you tried it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

> `SnackBar`'s parent view will tell on which container or layout will
>   the snackbar should be drawn. usually, snackbar looks for co-ordinator
>   layout as a parent from the view you passed as the argument if it
>   could not find one it'll take activity content layout
>   (android.R.id.content) Framelayout as a parent.

Code taken from `SnackBar`

```
@Nullable
    private static ViewGroup findSuitableParent(View view) {
        ViewGroup fallback = null;
        do {
            if (view instanceof CoordinatorLayout) {
                // We've found a CoordinatorLayout, use it
                return (ViewGroup) view;
            } else if (view instanceof FrameLayout) {
                if (view.getId() == android.R.id.content) {
                    // If we've hit the decor content view, then we didn't find a CoL in the
                    // hierarchy, so use it.
                    return (ViewGroup) view;
                } else {
                    // It's not the content view but we'll use it as our fallback
                    fallback = (ViewGroup) view;
                }
            }
            if (view != null) {
                // Else, we will loop and crawl up the view hierarchy and try to find a parent
                final ViewParent parent = view.getParent();
                view = parent instanceof View ? (View) parent : null;
            }
        } while (view != null);
        // If we reach here then we didn't find a CoL or a suitable content view so we'll fallback
        return fallback;
    }
```

> `BaseTransientBottomBar`'s anchor will tell on top of which view
>   snackbar will be shown.

Code taken from `BaseTransientBottomBar`

```
private int calculateBottomMarginForAnchorView() {
    if (anchorView == null) {
      return 0;
    }

    int[] anchorViewLocation = new int[2];
    anchorView.getLocationOnScreen(anchorViewLocation);
    int anchorViewAbsoluteYTop = anchorViewLocation[1];

    int[] targetParentLocation = new int[2];
    targetParent.getLocationOnScreen(targetParentLocation);
    int targetParentAbsoluteYBottom = targetParentLocation[1] + targetParent.getHeight();

    return targetParentAbsoluteYBottom - anchorViewAbsoluteYTop;
  }
```

...

```
/** Sets the view the {@link BaseTransientBottomBar} should be anchored above. */
  @NonNull
  public B setAnchorView(@Nullable View anchorView) {
    this.anchorView = anchorView;
    return (B) this;
  }

  /**
   * Sets the id of the view the {@link BaseTransientBottomBar} should be anchored above.
   *
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the anchor view is not found.
   */
  @NonNull
  public B setAnchorView(@IdRes int anchorViewId) {
    this.anchorView = targetParent.findViewById(anchorViewId);
    if (this.anchorView == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to find anchor view with id: " + anchorViewId);
    }
    return (B) this;
  }
```

You can find the source code the SnackBar here [Material SnackBar](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/snackbar/Snackbar.java)
and BaseTransientBottomBar here [BaseTransientBottomBar](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/snackbar/BaseTransientBottomBar.java)

Comment: Thanks, can you please explain the difference between with an example?

 `on top of which view snackbar will be shown` vs. `on which container or layout will the snackbar should be drawn.`